# Refresh an Azure AD user's group and administrative role memberships using Graph API

Tags: azure, entra-id

Is it possible to refresh a user's Azure AD group and administrative role memberships through the Graph API to avoid the delay before these changes take effect? Azure PIM does this when a user activates access.

The beta version of the Graph API has a [method to invalidate a user's refresh tokens](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-invalidateallrefreshtokens?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http&viewFallbackFrom=graph-rest-1.0) which looks like it does this, but the user has to log in again on all devices. I'd like to avoid that.